# How to "ignore" a picked up exchange from Apache Camel File Consumer

Tags: java, apache-camel, enterprise-integration

I have a batch file consumer that is polling a public directory that many different processes drop files to.  These files are "batched" together via a guid that is on the filename.  Once a particular batch is completed, the applications drop a .done file to trigger the camel file consumer.

My question is that i'm trying to find a way to potentially "ignore" messages/exchange that could have files that I don't want to process (ie.. aren't a part of my current batch).

Additionally, I'd like the "ignored" exchange to not be processed by camel (ie.. not moved to .processed directory).

I'm currently looking at the message filter as a potential way to do this, although i'm not sure if it will full fill my requirement to not process.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I have tried using the include, but that didn't work as I pick up the batch id from the .done file once it is dropped.  I then went the route of the pluggable filter.  That seemed to work ok, but the .done file now longer appears to control processing, as the polling runs endlessly with the "ignore" file just sitting in the directory.

Comment: I'm confused by what you think isn't working properly... it is normal expected behaviour for polling to run endlessly and ignored files to just sit in the directory. What is your expected outcome?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the 'include' or 'antinclude' (or 'exclude, and 'antexclude') parameters on the File component to only process specific messages, based on regex or ant pattern. Files that aren't processed won't be moved or touched at all.

If you need a more complicated set of rules than can be achieved by regex or ant pattern, you may need to write your own custom pluggable filter, which you can then specify using the 'filter' parameter.

See here for more details on the above:

http://camel.apache.org/file2.html